# How can I write the axioms for a semiring of sets in formal logic?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I know exactly what the axioms for a semiring of sets are, but I was looking for a way to write them in formal logic.
I'm especially pointing to the third axiom asserting the existence of a finite sequence of disjoint sets from the semiring itself.
Can you help?

Thanks as usual! :)

Comment: Wikipedia has them just about written out, the only thing missing being the quantifiers...

Comment: Maybe my question needs clarification; I was pointing to the third axiom in particular asserting the existence of a finite sequence of disjoint sets: how can I write this axiom in formal logic?

Comment: When you say 'formal logic', do you just mean set theory? Are you dissatisfied with the definition given on Wikipedia and just want a way of saying "there exists a finite number of mutually disjoint sets"?

Comment: The axioms are clear and perfect to work with, it's purely a game of writing them using the rules given by mathematical logic. As for the third axiom, I cannot write something like $\exists x_1...\exists x_n(...)$ without knowing in advance the exact number of sets in the sequence and I don't know how to solve this limitation.

Comment: Do you get my answer?

Comment: Yeah! Absolutely! I was busy with my own things, Sorry about that.

Comment: @DanieleLeo: Oh okay then would you accept my answer? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it is **impossible** to formalize [the desired axiomatization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets#Related_structures) in FOL, just as it is impossible to [axiomatize the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Axioms) in FOL. You can do this in SOL (second-order logic) with full semantics, but of course the consequence is that what are models of the resulting axiomatization would be sensitive to the meta-system.

In particular, we can prove the claimed impossibility by compactness of FOL. Take any FOL theory $S$ that axiomatizes only semi-ring families. Let $L$ be the language of $S$ plus new constant-symbols $A,B$. For each natural $k$, let $φ_k$ be an FOL sentence over $L$ that states ( $A ∖ B$ is not a union of $k$ members of the family ). Note that $φ_k$ needs $k$ quantifiers. But for each natural $k$ there is a model $M_k$ of $S ∪ \{ φ_i : 0≤i≤k \}$, namely the family $\{ \varnothing \} ∪ \{ \{x\} : x∈[0..k] \} ∪ \{ [0..k] \}$, since $[0..k] ∖ \varnothing$ is not the union of $k$ members of the family. Thus by compactness $S ∪ \{ φ_i : i∈\mathbb{N} \}$ is consistent and has a model, contradicting the definition of $S$.